# How Do I Create Custom Actions in Play! 2.0 Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I would like to make a custom  `play.api.mvc.Action` in play that:

1. will parse and return some custom data in the request (such as access tokens, or protocol buffers)
2. can be chained with other actions

For Example:

```
def something = DecodeAccessToken { token: AccessToken => 
  Action {
    // do something with token
    Ok
  }
}
```

If the token is not present, the `DecodeAccessToken` action should return early with either `Unauthorized` or `BadRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the [approach recommended in the Play! documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaActionsComposition), but I would write this as:

```
def DecodeAccessToken(body: AccessToken => Result)(implicit request: Request[_]): Result = {
  val token: AccessToken = // deserialize token from request
  body(token)
}

def something = Action { implicit request =>
  DecodeAccessToken { token: AccessToken =>
    Ok
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic template as follows:

```
trait DecodeAccessToken[A] extends Action[A]
object DecodeAccessToken {
  def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: AccessToken=>Request[A] => Result) = new DecodeAccessToken[A] {
    def parser = bodyParser
    def apply(req: Request[A]) = {
      val token: AccessToken = //deserialize token from request

      // If there is a problem with the token, do not call `block` below
      // Instead just return Results.BadRequest

      block(token)(req)
    }
  }
  def apply(block: AccessToken => Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    DecodeAccessToken(BodyParsers.parse.anyContent)(block)
  }
}
```